# how can i trigger ajax error callback on success callback?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, callback

I'm looking for a way to trigger ajax error in success callback. i have tried to explain my problem code below:

```
$.ajax({
url: requestURL,
data: postData,
type: 'post',
success: function(response){
    if(response.Success){
        // do something
    }else{
        // request workflow fails in this case,
        // i have to trigger this ajax request's error callback
    }
},
error: function(){
    // do something on error case
},
dataType: 'json'
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var errorhandler = function(xhr, textStatus, error){
    // do something on error case
};

$.ajax({
   url: requestURL,
   data: postData,
   type: 'post',
   success: function(response){
       if(response.Success){
           // do something
       }else{
           errorhandler();
       }
   },
   error: errorhandler,
   dataType: 'json'
   });
```

Comment: Make sure you do this though:
`errorhandler.apply(this,arguments);` to ensure the scope and arguments are still there (they won't be the same, but they'll be good enough).

Comment: @balupton: in general, I agree. But in this particular case scope doesn't matter. No need to access `this` within the error handler.

Comment: yes i'm doing this with a way which you suggested, but for example, i have set up global ajax error callback with $.ajaxSetup. and i want to trigger that callback. actually i'm looking way to call this callback error case, over that $.ajax call. But yes this is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could send an appropriate HTTP status code so the error callback is triggered automatically.

The [4xx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) error range which pertains to client errors might be a good fit. Most API's make use of HTTP statuses to indicate error along with additional JSON/XML data as you're doing. See [Twitter's response codes](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/responses_errors) for an example.

Comment: i can't touch server-side environment and i'm looking for client-side and i'm looking for a way to call inside success case.